# array as function param

Tags: javascript, arrays, actionscript-3, function

I have flash application, which creates array and calls javascript function.

```
var jsParams = ["3011","3012","3013","3014","3015"];
ExternalInterface.call("doCall", jsParams);
```

And this is my javascript function:

```
function doCall(params) {
  console.log(params);
  console.log(params[0]);
}
```

The output in the firebug is:

```
["3011","3012","3013","3014","3015"]
[
```

But for the second line i was expecting 3011 and not [. Then i have tried to call same function with same params from firebug and the function outputed:

```
doCall(["3011","3012","3013","3014","3015"]);
["3011","3012","3013","3014","3015"]
3011
```

My question is how to pass params from actionscript to javascript as array and not as string value.

Thanks.

Comment: If I test your code, it works fine. What version of FireFox and Flash are you running?

Comment: Firefox: 9.0.1; Flash: 11.1.102.55 (win7 x64)

Comment: It also works in chrome. Any other information you can give?

Comment: `console.log(params[0]);` giving `[` indicates that the parameter is received as a string, doesn't it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send array from Flash (AS3) to JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058589/send-array-from-flash-as3-to-javascript)

Comment: @taskinoor many thanks! I couldn't find any question like mine, so i've posted it. But it looks like, that someone was already asking about this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `params` variable is being passed in as a string, rather than an array.

Square bracket notation, when applied to a string, represents the character at the supplied index, which in this case would be the '[' (position 0).

You should look into JSON decoding to find a safe way to convert the string back into an array , I wouldn't recommend `eval`, and `JSON.decode` isn't widely supported.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried encapsulating the array within another array?

ExternalInterface.call("doCall", [jsParams]);

I think a initial array is so you can pass mulitple sets of parameters

Comment: What i had to do is, to replace jsParams from string to array. Then i just passed array ExternalInterface.call("doCall", jsParams);